# ActiveX: Could not load Driver

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, activex, javascript

I am having a look [**at this example**](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5201) which makes use of activeX - it does extacly what I need from the description but everytime I try to run the example, I get the error:

> Could not load Drivers. The ActiveX
>   Control could not be started.

I have tried this on IE8 on a windows Vista Machine. What is the problem, how can I get those drivers?

This is my first time with ActiveX.

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the strong caveat that this should only be done on an intranet, the error is "Could not load Drives" not Drivers. This error is raised by that script when it is rightly prevented from creating an instance of `Scripting.FileSystemObject` by the browsers security policy.

On a public web page the visitor would have to reconfigure their local security settings in order for this to work ([example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/27092b49-7d3e-4d86-9ffb-223a26037c3f))